# Restrict to 2 digits after decimal

Tags: magento-1.9

My code...

```
 <a class="head01" href="#">
    ITEM(S):<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount(); ?> 
    TOTAL:<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); ?>
        <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
<a class="head01" href="#">
  ITEM(S):<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount(); ?> TOTAL:<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); ?>
 <?php echo number_format(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal(), 2, '.', ''); ?>
</a>
```

Below code for price format with currency symbol:

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency((Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal(), true, false);
```